# Java to display words from my text file in descending order?

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

So i have this coding that needs to read words from a the text file in a LinkedList and use an iterator on it to displays
all the words (duplicates allowed) in descending alphabetical order (4 words “tab” separated per line), compare the time to traverse the list using an iterator vs. using the get(index) method.

So far I am able to get it to display in ascending order but not descending.  What i tried is behind the // lines:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Check number of arguments passed

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: TextFile");
            System.exit(0);

        }
String filename = args[0];

TreeSet<String>treeSet = new TreeSet<String>();
try
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.nextLine())!=null)
    {
        String[] tokens = line.split("[||n|\t|\r|.|,|)|(|-|\"]");



        for (int i = 0; i  < tokens.length; i++)
        //for (int i = tokens.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
            treeSet.add(tokens[i]);

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}

Iterator iterator = treeSet.iterator();

System.out.println("\nDisplay words in ascending order");

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
System.out.println(iterator.next());

}
}
}
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use this :

```
List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>(treeSet);
Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Now array list will have your strings in reverse order, you can iterate on this array list to print them. Hope this is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
    TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Yes this approach also will do. Thanks.